# Akka and blocking operations

Tags: asynchronous, akka, blocking

I have an akka system where 99% of request involve blocking DB calls. I was wondering if there is any benefit in such system of executing blocking operations in separate dispatcher\threadpool, as described in best practices.

While akka threads will be idle waiting, the threadpool task queue can be either overflow memory or start to reject new tasks, which an actor has ho handle somehow.

I understand that this is common question, but I cannot find any relevant article or discussion.

Comment: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/dispatchers.html#blocking-needs-careful-management

Comment: @chunjef Thank you, I read that before, but they have an example with one actor that is not blocking, whether my question is "if there any benefit if all actors/operations are blocking"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Akka project is very supportive of the [Reactive Manifesto](http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/). The documentation assumes that by using Akka you are also interested in building a system according to the Reactive Manifesto.

A key part of the Reactive Manifesto is that systems should remain responsive at all times. If you used the same dispatcher/thread pool for the blocking DB operations as for your main Akka routing infrastructure, it is possible that all the Akka threads could be occupied by the DB operations, and your system would effectively be deadlocked until one of the DB operations completes. This might not be a problem for a simple system on a single JVM that only performs this task, but it's easy to think of new features that would make this a problem:

1. Suppose you wanted to add an admin page that showed the number of DB requests currently in flight and the number that are waiting to be executed by one of the DB threads. This page should remain responsive at all times, even when all the DB threads are blocked, therefore the code that serves this page should use a different dispatcher that can't be blocked by the DB.
2. Suppose you wanted to add multiple JVMs to your system accross multiple different machines, either to increase scale or to improve reliability with some fault tolerance. This involves various gossip messages and heartbeats to be sent across the network. If these system messages were delayed because of the blocking DB operations then the cluster would not work correctly.

A separate dispatcher could be useful for another reason. You probably want to throttle access to the database so that your system does not overload the database. You could make the DB dispatcher a fixed size thread pool and use that as a crude but effective way to throttle your database requests. The alternative would be to implement some buffers withing your actors but this will require a lot of extra code (although you might have to do this anyway if you are worried about running out of memory because of too many tasks etc).

Comment: Thank you, I did not think about system messages like heartbeats before.
But can you point me where I can read about "some buffers within your actors" to address possible OOM problem with tasks queue for DB thread pool?

Comment: A bounded mailbox on your blocking DB actor would be one way, but then the requester would not know if task was accepted. You can have a non-blocking actor maintain a queue of requests with max size. On every request, it can forward it to the blocking DB actor if there aren't too many in progress, add it to the queue, or send a rejection message if the queue is full. When the DB actor responds you can use some request ID to respond to the original requester, remove the request from the queue and decrement the number of active requests (and forward the next waiting request to DB actor).